# How to import multiple csv-files in Excel at once with VBA

Tags: microsoft-excel, vba, csv

I am trying to import multiple csv-files within the same directory into my Excel sheet using VBA. The following code is working very well with just one csv-file. But I lack the knowledge to adapt my VBA script to import all data into the same Excel sheet. If anyone can help me I will be very grateful. The data from the next csv-file needs to be imported to the first empty row of the same sheet.

```
    Sub loadDataFromCSV()
Const csvFile = "N:\Temp voor automatisering\*.csv"
Dim ws As Worksheet, csv As Workbook, cCount As Long, cName As String

Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Application.DisplayAlerts = False
Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("NGSimport")
'Set ws = ThisWorkbook.ActiveSheet
Workbooks.Open csvFile
Set csv = ActiveWorkbook
cName = csv.Name
ActiveSheet.Columns("A:U").Copy
ws.Activate
ws.Range("A1:U1").PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
'cCount = Selection.Cells.Count
csv.Close

Application.DisplayAlerts = True
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
```

End Sub

Comment: [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10380312/loop-through-files-in-a-folder-using-vba) or [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63286632/vba-excel-loop-through-all-xslm-files-in-the-same-directory) may be useful.

Comment: Excuse for the late reply cybernetic.nomad I overlooked your comment. Thank you, I will give it a try.